# Issue while reading openshift template from repository(bitbucket)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, openshift, openshift-enterprise

I have a jenkins pipeline script to create an app using openshift template placed in a repository(Bit Bucket). However, i get the below mentioned error everytime.

Note: I have configured credentials in Jenkins as well.

Version
openshift v3.11.200
kubernetes v1.11.0+d4cacc0

Steps To Reproduce
PipeLine Script:

```
// path of the template to use
def templatePath = 'https://xxxx/git/users/pdeb/repos/mashery-local/raw/acs/tml-acs-template.json'
// name of the template that will be created
def templateName = 'mashery-local'
// NOTE, the "pipeline" directive/closure from the declarative pipeline syntax needs to include, or be nested outside,
// and "openshift" directive/closure from the OpenShift Client Plugin for Jenkins.  Otherwise, the declarative pipeline engine
// will not be fully engaged.
pipeline {

    agent any

    stages {
        stage('preamble') {
            steps {
                script {
                    openshift.withCluster() {
                        openshift.withProject() {
                            echo "Using project: ${openshift.project()}"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('cleanup') {
            steps {
                script {
                    openshift.withCluster() {
                        openshift.withProject() {
                            // delete everything with this template label
                            openshift.selector("all", [ template : templateName ]).delete()
                            // delete any secrets with this template label
                            if (openshift.selector("secrets", templateName).exists()) {
                                openshift.selector("secrets", templateName).delete()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } // script
            } // steps
        } // stage
        stage('create') {
            steps {
                script {
                    openshift.withCluster() {
                        openshift.withProject() {
                            // create a new application from the templatePath
                            openshift.newApp(templatePath)
                        }
                    }
                } // script
            } // steps
        } // stage
    } // stages
} // pipeline
```

Current Result:

```
*ERROR: new-app returned an error;
{reference={}, err=error: unable to load template file "https://rndwww.nce.amadeus.net/git/users/pdeb/repos/mashery-local-on-acs/raw/acs/tml-acs-template.json": unable to decode "https://rndwww.nce.amadeus.net/git/users/pdeb/repos/mashery-local-on-acs/raw/acs/tml-acs-template.json": couldn't get version/kind; json parse error: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type struct { APIVersion string "json:\"apiVersion,omitempty\""; Kind string "json:\"kind,omitempty\"" }
error: git ls-remote failed with: fatal: https://rndwww.nce.amadeus.net/git/users/pdeb/repos/mashery-local-on-acs/raw/acs/tml-acs-template.json/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?;  local file access failed with: stat https://rndwww.nce.amadeus.net/git/users/pdeb/repos/mashery-local-on-acs/raw/acs/tml-acs-template.json: no such file or directory
error: unable to locate any images in image streams, templates loaded in accessible projects, template files, local docker images with name "https://rndwww.nce.amadeus.net/git/users/pdeb/repos/mashery-local-on-acs/raw/acs/tml-acs-template.json"
Argument 'https://rndwww.nce.amadeus.net/git/users/pdeb/repos/mashery-local-on-acs/raw/acs/tml-acs-template.json' was classified as an image, image~source, or loaded template reference.
The 'oc new-app' command will match arguments to the following types:
  1. Images tagged into image streams in the current project or the 'openshift' project
     - if you don't specify a tag, we'll add ':latest'
  2. Images in the Docker Hub, on remote registries, or on the local Docker engine
  3. Templates in the current project or the 'openshift' project
  4. Git repository URLs or local paths that point to Git repositories
--allow-missing-images can be used to point to an image that does not exist yet.
See 'oc new-app -h' for examples., verb=new-app, cmd=oc --server=https://10.224.0.1:443 --certificate-authority=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt --namespace=lhmdw-tml-dev --token=XXXXX new-app https://rndwww.nce.amadeus.net/git/users/pdeb/repos/mashery-local-on-acs/raw/acs/tml-acs-template.json -o=json , out=, status=1}
Finished: FAILURE*
```

Expected Result:
To run the template successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The following error message indicates that your template file has an incorrect format:

```
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type struct { APIVersion string "json:\"apiVersion,omitempty\""; Kind string "json:\"kind,omitempty\"" }
```

So you should fix the content of the template `tml-acs-template.json`, as currently this file cannot be used.